# Index with nested match does not return expected values

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, match, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am trying to get a cell to output the name of the item that is on the same row as the target cell.

This is the code I am using (D17 is relative to the row):

```
=index(Sheet2!C$2:C$15; match($D17; Sheet2!D$2:D$15); 0)
```

And this is what it outputs:

[image]

I have no idea why it's not working, and I do not know why it outputs the same item name several times. A copy of the sheet can be found [here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17NqPUonvSvtVJKZQn7CAv8fyiElCeIv2myc27k73qoQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you include desired output in your sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D13:D; {Blad2!D$2:D$15\Blad2!A$2:A$15}; 2; 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I just realized now the sheet was a bit of a mess, and I'm sorry I didn't get to replying earlier, but your code did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, is there a way to remove automatic hyperlinks? I tried looking it up and several sources said tools > preferences, but that option is not in the tools menu for me.

Comment: select range > right-click > unlink - https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuHzC.png